# Android NDK Compile error NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, android-studio

I tried run ijkplayer and I recieved this error.

```
  C:\ndk\ndk-build.cmd NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null
```

I think is something with the build.gradle but I don't know what.

My ndk directory is on *c:\ndk* and I have ndk 32bit.

I appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your build (gradle ?) is not passing proper path to the root of your project to `ndk-build.cmd`.

You can run the `ndk-build.cmd` from command line. Open a command prompt, `cd` into your module folder (it should have `jni` folder) , and run `c:\ndk\ndk-build.cmd` it will use the current path as the `NDK_PROJECT_PATH`

Comment: Is there a way to tell gradle to pass the proper path to the root of the project to `ndk-build`? So it can be automatically built with the project?

Comment: @Ianlet gradle support for ndk evolved a lot over last few updates, i suggest you use AndroidStudio to create a NDK hello-world app, and copy/create the same generated gradle options in your project.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do use the AndroidStudio but I am restricted to use the NDK r8d with gradle 1.12 and I read somewhere this could cause the problem. But that's a different question from this one so I will continue to investigate on this and maybe post a new question.

Comment: @ashoke How do you create an NDK hello-world app? Are you talking about a template?

Comment: Hello, Excuse me. After I did what as you said, I got this erro:jni/jni-helper.cpp:20:10: fatal error: 'ancillary.h' file not found... Can u help me with? Thank u.