# Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file:198

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I am trying to build [this](https://github.com/pcgod/mumble-android) mumble client for android and I am having hard time trying to get the ndk to compile the project.
When I try to compile from android studio IDE I get the following error: `Error while executing process 'path'\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT='path'\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK='path'\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-9 NDK_OUT='path'/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT='path'\ndkBuild\debug\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}` 
After some research, I added an environment path to the root of my project following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23114112/3551661) answer but it didn't help. 
I also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26184104/3551661) answer to get around the `NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null` by running the `ndk-build.cmd` from command line, but this gave me the following error: `Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: 'path'\ndk-build.cmd/jni/Android.mk
'path'/android-ndk/build//../build/core/add-application.mk:198: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.`
In case it is needed, here is my `Android.mk` file:

```
ROOT := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH          := $(ROOT)/celt/libcelt
LOCAL_MODULE        := libcelt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := bands.c          celt.c              cwrs.c              dump_modes.c \
                       entcode.c        entdec.c            entenc.c            header.c \
                       kiss_fft.c       laplace.c           mdct.c              modes.c \
                       pitch.c          quant_bands.c       rangedec.c          rangeenc.c \
                       rate.c           testcelt.c          vq.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS        := -I$(LOCAL_PATH) -I$(ROOT)/celt_wrapper -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fvisibility=hidden
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH          := $(ROOT)/speex/libspeex
LOCAL_MODULE        := libspeex
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := cb_search.c      exc_10_32_table.c   exc_8_128_table.c   filters.c \
                       gain_table.c     hexc_table.c        high_lsp_tables.c   lsp.c \
                       ltp.c            speex.c             stereo.c            vbr.c \
                       vq.c bits.c      exc_10_16_table.c   exc_20_32_table.c   exc_5_256_table.c \
                       exc_5_64_table.c gain_table_lbr.c    hexc_10_32_table.c  lpc.c \
                       lsp_tables_nb.c  modes.c             modes_wb.c          nb_celp.c \
                       quant_lsp.c      sb_celp.c           speex_callbacks.c   speex_header.c \
                       window.c         resample.c          jitter.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS        := -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/../include -D__EMX__ -DFIXED_POINT -DEXPORT=''
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PATH              := $(ROOT)/new
LOCAL_MODULE            := libnative
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := hawtjni.c hawtjni_native.c hawtjni_native_stats.c hawtjni_native_structs.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS            := -I$(ROOT)/celt/libcelt -fvisibility=hidden
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES  := libcelt libspeex

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and the `application.mk` file contains the following line:

```
#APP_OPTIM := debug
```

Any clues on how to fix this would be appreciated.